# Macro to list all documents field value only select list

Tags: kentico

I am trying to list all items in a section of Kentico as a drop-down list but want only one field value to be returned for each document.

What I have tried

**Lists Nothing:**

`Documents.WithAllData["/Foo/Bar/Bar"].AllChildren.WithAllData.All.GetValue("FooBar")`

**Lists all document information:**

```
Documents.WithAllData["/Foo/Bar/Bar"].AllChildren
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd use a macro similar to this:

```
<select id="ddlItems">
{% Documents["/Foo/Bar/Bar"].Children.WithAllData.ApplyTransformation("cms.event.transformationname") %}
</select>
```

To list out all your items.  The transformation will then have your column information:

`<option>{% FooBar %}</option>`

**** UPDATE ****
Based on your comment, you can simply use a sql query (which a macro will run anyway).  If you know what page type you want to query you can go directly to that page type's table:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, FROM Content_YourTable
```

If you need the data from your page type based on a particular path in the tree, then you can use something like this:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM View_CMS_Tree_Joined
    INNER JOIN CONTENT_MenuItem on DocumentForeignKeyValue = MenuItemID
WHERE NodeAliasPath like '/Foo/Bar/Bar/%'
    AND Classname = 'cms.menuitem'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to get this to populate into another page type field as a Drop-down list.